# Parse XML SOAP response php

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm using the following code to send an request to a SOAP service:

```
header('Content-type: application/xml');

function doXMLCurl($url,$postXML){
    $CURL = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postXML); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: text/xml','Content-Type: application/soap+xml'));
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $xmlResponse = curl_exec($CURL); 
    return $xmlResponse;
}

$input_xml = '<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">.....</s:Envelope>';

echo doXMLCurl('webservice_url', $input_xml);
```

The responde is a XML too.

How can i parse this data or convert to an array or object? I tried with *simplexml_load_string()* but without success.

EDIT

XML Response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">...</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <ListStatesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <ListStatesResult xmlns:b="..." xmlns:i="...">
            <b:Return>0</b:Return>
            <b:Message i:nil="true"/>
            <b:Status>00</b:Status>
            <b:ListStates>
               <b:States>
                  <b:Description>ACRE</b:Description>
                  <b:Code>AC</b:Code>
               </b:States>
               <b:States>
                  <b:Description>ALAGOAS</b:Description>
                  <b:Code>AL</b:Code>
               </b:States>
               <b:States>
                  <b:Description>AMAZONAS</b:Description>
                  <b:Code>AM</b:Code>
               </b:States>
                ...
            </b:ListStates>
         </ListStatesResult>
      </ListStatesResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the `$xmlResponse` ?

Comment: Yes! Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `xml` is valid, you can use [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php), i.e.:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlResponse);
echo $xml->node->otherNode['Id'];
```

To loop it, use:

```
foreach ($xml->node->otherNode as $el) {
  foreach($el as $key => $val) {
   echo "{$key}: {$val}";
  }
}
```

Comment: print_r($xml)

returns only SimpleXMLElement Object ( )

Answer (score -1):

I found the easiest way is to use json functions

```
$jsonObject = json_decode(json_encode($xmlString));
```

Then `print_r($jsonObject)` to find the structure. This allows attributes to be accessible to using `$jsonObject->{'@attributes'}->id;`

Comment: Not working, this the same response soap...